# Not able to decode UTF-8 encoded json text with Cpanel::JSON::XS

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to decode an UTF-8 encoded json string with [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':std', ':encoding(utf-8)';
use utf8;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $str = '{ "title": "Outlining — How to outline" }';
my $hash = decode_json $str;
#my $hash = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode_json( $str );
print Dumper($hash);
```

but this throws an exception at `decode_json`:

```
Wide character in subroutine entry
```

I also tried `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode_json( $str )` (see commented out line), but this gives another error:

```
malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode_json` expects UTF-8, but you are providing decoded text (a string of Unicode Code Points).

Use

```perl
use utf8;
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );

my $json_utf8 = encode_utf8( '{ "title": "Outlining — How to outline" }' );

my $data = decode_json( $json_utf8 );
```

or

```perl
use utf8;

my $json_utf8 = do { no utf8; '{ "title": "Outlining — How to outline" }' };

my $data = decode_json( $json_utf8 );
```

or

```perl
use utf8;

my $json_ucp = '{ "title": "Outlining — How to outline" }';

my $data = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->decode( $json_ucp );    # Implied: ->utf8(0)
```

(The middle one seems hackish to me. The first one might be used if you get data from multiple source, and the others provide it encoded.)

Comment: Thanks! The first approach works fine, but the third still gives an exception `malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")`

Comment: I am accepting this since it solved my problem. Still it would be interesting to know why the third approach fails

Comment: 1) I don't know what you mean by "still". Do you think I merely copied your code? No, I fixed *two* errors in your code. 2) End of string at offset zero means you passed an empty string. So you obviously didn't use my code :)

Comment: Yeah, I knew I overlooked something :) The problem was I was not copying your code but instead modified my own. As you can see from my question I was erroneously using `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode_json( $str )` when I should be using `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode( $str )`

Comment: No, you should be using `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->decode( $str )`. Like I said, I corrected *two* errors.